# Representing a Concept

Tags: lattice-orders, data-analysis

From Formal Concept Analysis:

If I have a set of objects:

G={Shark, Penguin, Bat}

and a set of attributes:

M={Breathe Underwater, Can Fly, has Vertebrae}

and I make a chart to represent my context (G,M,I) where I is the incidence relation (If my object g has attribute m, I mark an X in the chart)

```
        | Breate Underwater | Can Fly | Has Vertebrae|
Shark   |          X        |         |    X         |
Penguin |                   |         |    X         |
Bat     |                   |   X     |    X         |
```

How do I represent my concept C(G,M,I)?

I know the sets of objects that fit in C(G,M,I) are

{{Shark},{Bat},{Shark,Penguin,Bat}}

but this leaves out the attributes and the incidence relation. I can represent {C(G,M,I); <=} as a Galois Lattice or Concept Lattice. I am just not sure how to represent C(G,M,I).

Comment: What about as a function $G\times M\to\{\texttt{true},\texttt{false}\}$? Or, just as a subset of $G\times M$? It also depends on what you want to use it for later.

Comment: That works for representing my context, but I am trying to represent the concept created from the context.

Comment: It is easier to create the lattice, if I find the concept first. If I were to type up an example of how to get from a context to a concept lattice, I would need to include the concept. I would be unsure how to represent it.

Comment: Ahh.. are you talking about 'formal concept analysis'.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm talking about

Comment: They don't mention how to write concepts though. Just contexts and Concept Lattices

Comment: Perhaps rather than editing your question to include a colon, you could edit the post to clarify, and touch upon what Berci brought up?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to clarify.